# How do I reference a name in a different input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

Program:

```py
CLASS = str(input("What is the name of your class: "))
HOURS = int(input("How many hours a week do you spend in", CLASS))
```

the second line does work, the first line work and then crashes once it gets to the second line.

I;ve tried googling and looking through my notes and nothering explaines it

Comment: Not related to your question, but it is better practice to name variables using lowercase letters. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Rachel! You already have good answers and a nice comment by Selcuk, but for the next time I invite you to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`input` does not work like `print` in regards to how each takes arguments. `print` uses varargs, which allows it to accept an arbitrary number of arguments and automatically concatenates them for you. `input` has no such functionality though. You need to do the concatenation yourself.

I'd use f-strings here:

```
HOURS = int(input(f"How many hours a week do you spend in {CLASS}"))
```

or, using `+`:

```
HOURS = int(input(f"How many hours a week do you spend in " + CLASS))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function in python only takes 1 argument, and you gave it 2 (a comma indicates a new input).

Their are two main ways to do this:

The first way to do this is via string formatting, this would look like this:

```py
HOURS = int(input(f"How many hours a week do you spend in {CLASS}"))
```

Generally this is the best way to do this. The f at the beginning of the int string allows you to put variables into the string using curly brackets.

The other way to do this is to make the string for input a completley new variable, like this:

```py
HOURS_str = "How many hours a week do you spend in " + CLASS
HOURS = int(input(HOURS_str))
```

Here, a new variable, `HOURS_str` is made, and this variable is then referenced in the input.

You can also put the whole of hours string into the input for a third method:

```py
HOURS = int(input("How many hours a week do you spend in " + CLASS))
```